# Can pulling with Thorn Whip generate an Opportunity Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, opportunity-attack

Let's say my party member is around 30 feet in front of me and engaged with a monster in melee close combat.

If I successfully cast Thorn Whip and pull the monster 10 feet closer to me, will this generate an opportunity attack for my party member who is next to the monster?

Comment: This question was asked 2 years and 7 months ago, so this is not a duplicate. The questiuon Rubiksmoose is refering to was asked yerterday

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, this won't generate opportunity attacks. The rules on opportunity attacks include this clause:

> You also don’t provoke an
>   opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone
>   or something moves you without using your movement,
>   action, or reaction.

If a creature doesn't use its own movement, or its own action, it doesn't cause opportunity attacks.