# Can I make an opportunity attack against a grappled creature if it's being moved out of my reach?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, grapple

We just recently started using the grapple mechanics in D&D 5e. I was wondering if it was possible to set up multiple opportunity attacks by grappling an enemy creature and then moving it out of your allies reach.

Since it is not specifically forbidden in any of the rulings pertaining to grapple or opportunity attacks, I'm inclined to allow it in my games.
This does create a power balancing problem though, giving advantage to the bigger group (which seems only logical). Making an encounter with 10 low level enemies possibly more dangerous then an encounter with 1 high level enemy.

I would like to know if any other DM's have run into this issue, or maybe its no issue at all.

Comment: Related, possibly dupe: [When can I make opportunity attacks?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44402/23064), and [Can pulling with Thorn Whip generate an Opportunity Attack?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68098/23064)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually covered by the *opportunity attack* rules:

> You also don't provoke an opportunity attack [...] when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.

<sup>PHB, pg.195</sup>

Since moving a grappled creature uses *your* movement, not the grappled creature's, it does not provoke opportunity attacks against the grappled creature.

Comment: Thank you very much for this insanely quick reply, this will allow me to clear up the rules at my table instantly without having them use this (illegal) move) and me having to take it away. lol