# Can I grapple and drag someone to grant opportunity attacks against them?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, grapple

I play a Goliath Valor Bard in a 5e D&D campaign.
After a bit of Google searching about valor bards I came across the word of a role called a "Grappler", which Goliaths and bards are apparently good at.

I want to ask you if this combo works:

- First round, you try to grapple your enemy
- Second round, you try to shove your enemy

So now they are grappled and prone

- You "order" or ask your melee teammates to position themself on the other side of the enemy
- Third round you drag your grappled-, prone enemy, so all your teammmates get attack of opportunity

If this works, it means that every teammate other than the grappler (me) gets to attack twice per round.

Would this work, mechanically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can I make opportunity attacks?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44402/when-can-i-make-opportunity-attacks) Or maybe more accurately [Can I make an opportunity attack against a grappled creature if it's being moved out of my reach?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95317/can-i-make-an-opportunity-attack-against-a-grappled-creature-if-its-being-moved) which is closed as a dupe of the previous one anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It doesn't work

Grappling and shoving are occasionally effective techniques in combat, but the crux of this plan seems to be the opportunity attack part, which does not work. Being dragged does not provoke opportunity attacks.

> ...You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport **or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action or reaction**. *(Player's Handbook, page 195, under "Opportunity attacks")*

You still get the usual benefits of fighting a prone, grappled foe, but no extra opportunity attacks.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your fast answer :) i am still going to be the role of a grappler. Especially since my DM is atm giving us more single-boss-fight-ish encounters. so last session i both grappled and shoved a large sized white dragon which was so cool. i just thought i could be of more use other than my attacks, cause giving 3-4 attack of opportunity sounds a lot stronger than my sword :D I can see that it wouldnt work, oh well. thx again :)

Comment: @ChristianThorstedJonasson No problem. If you found my answer helpful, kindly mark it as accepted by clicking the tickbox marker near the up- and downvote buttons.

Answer (score 1):

**Third round you drag your grappled-, prone enemy, so all your teammmates get attack of opportunity**

This does not work basic rules p74:

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you
>   can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you
>   use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking
>   creature. The attack interrupts the provoking creature’s movement,
>   occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.

PHB 195:

> You also don’t provoke an
>   opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something
>   moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction. For
>   example, you don’t provoke an opportunity attack if an explosion hurls
>   you out o f a foe’s reach or if gravity causes you to fall past an
>   enemy