# What happens when you have a creature grappled and use the Bait and Switch Maneuver to move 5 feet away from the creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, grapple, forced-movement

The Bait and Switch Maneuver (Battlemaster Fighter feature):

> *Bait and Switch*. When you're within 5 feet of a creature on your turn, you can expend one superiority die and switch places with that creature, provided you spend at least 5 feet of movement and the creature is willing and isn't incapacitated. This movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks.
>
> Roll the superiority die. Until the start of your next turn, you or the other creature (your choice) gains a bonus to AC equal to the number rolled.

Does it just break your grapple since the creature is outside your reach? Does this count as "Moving a Grappled Target" and the creature you're grappling moves 5 feet with you?

Or does this count as the latter, but since your speed is halved, and the maneuver only allows you to move 5 feet, your speed is 2.5 feet, and if playing on a grid, actually cannot move?

Comment: Related: [What happens when the UA Bait and Switch maneuver is used on a grappled ally when both the user and ally are still within the grappler's range?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161611/what-happens-when-the-ua-bait-and-switch-maneuver-is-used-on-a-grappled-ally-whe) (but not a dupe)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You can choose to bring the grappled creature with you, but it takes 10 feet of movement.

[Bait and Switch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/fighter#BaitandSwitch) says:

> When you’re within 5 feet of a creature on your turn, you can expend one superiority die and switch places with that creature, provided you spend at least 5 feet of movement

When you use Bait and Switch, *you are using your available movement*, so the rules for using it apply, that is, [bringing a creature with you costs twice as much movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#Grappling):

> When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

On a 5 foot grid, since you cannot move only 2.5 feet, you must move 5 feet, which costs 10 feet of movement when bringing a grappled creature along.